# Understanding Javascript compiler and maybe Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my Meteor App's server folder, I have server.js and helper.js

Inside helper.js I have for example:

```
import swisseph from 'swisseph'
SWISSEPH = {}
SWISSEPH.SWE_HOUSES_EX = Meteor.wrapAsync(swisseph.swe_houses_ex);
```

In my server.js file if I pass `SWISSEPH.SWE_HOUSES_EX` directly inside a function

```
const calc_longitudes_of_upagrahas = ( SWISSEPH.SWE_HOUSES_EX, flag,latitude, longitude, array_of_juls , index, obj ) => {};
```

I get this error:

```
While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.osx.x86_64):
server/server.js:488:43: Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters (488:43)
```

But if I first set `SWISSEPH.SWE_HOUSES_EX` inside another variable or const then it works:

```
const x = SWISSEPH.SWE_HOUSES_EX  //don't know why if I use SWISSEPH.SWE_HOUSES_EX directly I get an error

const calc_longitudes_of_upagrahas = ( x, flag,latitude, longitude, array_of_juls , index, obj ) => {};
```

What is the reason for this?
For me this is counterintuitive....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not call a function, but rather defines a new one:

```
const foo = (x, y, z) => {}
```

This syntax creates a new function named `foo` which takes three parameters. So your second code example works because the `x` is interpreted as a parameter; the first one fails because `SWISSEPH.SWE_HOUSES_EX` is not a valid parameter name.